# During automation testing Do you write test scripts first then write test cases or opposite?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation

I'm using Selenium WebDriver. What is the difference between unit test and writing scripts for test?

Answer (score 1):

generally we are writing manual test cases first then based upon that automation developer write the scripts as per test flow
unit test is a part of code which is independent and part of a script

Answer (score 0):

Test automation follows cycle for testing purpose.

1) Automation feasibility analysis

2) Test Strategy

3) Environment setup

4) Test script development

5) Test script execution

6) Test result generation and analysis

Its  good for a programmer/tester to follow test cycle.

A unit test focuses on a single “unit of code” – usually a function in an object or module. By making the test specific to a single function, the test should be simple, quick to write, and quick to run. This means you can have many unit tests, and more unit tests means more bugs caught. They are especially helpful if you need to change your code, as you can safely do so and trust that any other code will not break.

Where,
A test case, in software engineering, is a set of conditions under which a tester will determine whether an application, software system or one of its features is working as it was originally established for it to do.

Answer (score 0):

For new features, we always use manual testing first. Test automation requires a lot of effort and thus is only worthwhile for regression tests of established features, that would require even more effort if run manually again and again with every new release.

So the answer is: No test-driven approach with Selenium!

Anyway, it is a good idea, if you have the opportunity, to talk with the developers before they start their implementation, so they can design the HTML to make it easier for Selenium test case developers to find the elements inside the DOM, e.g. by placing ID's or custom attributes where needed.